# Android/XML: Is there a way to set images in specific places, rather than relative? Can they be set to scale properly when on a bigger device?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-imageview, android-xml

I have several images, that need to be in specific places, but remain separate images. For example, imagine I have an image of a face. The separate images would be the nose, the eyes, the lips, etc...

I need them in specific places on the face. The problem is two-fold:

1: I need to put them in specific locations. Relative layout doesn't seem to work super well. Unless I type the margin gaps in exactly.

2: The other issue is when I change to a different device, it screws up the positioning. If I manually enter in margins, when I move to a tablet, everything is screwed up again.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need an AbsoluteLayout, but since it has been deprecated so long, you can try to use FrameLayout to simulate it.

Comment: Can you expand on using frame layout to simulate AbsoluteLayout?

Comment: see my suggestion code below

Answer (score 0):

You can create nested Linear layouts , include your components and use `android:layout_weight` in each of them .If you  have high alignment constraints , create a separate layout for each component and accordingly use `android:orientation` in it. This way you won't have any positioning issues when you switch devices .

Comment: What does layout weight add here? How will it keep everything positioned?

Answer (score 0):

FYR

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP;  
layoutParams.leftMargin = x;  
layoutParams.topMargin = y;  

imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Is the imageview in your example the "face" or the various body parts attached to the face? I'm not sure from your example how I would align those.